# TestFlight doesn’t support apps with Watchkit extension

Tags: testflight, watchkit

After uploading the app via adHoc deployment I see this message on the iTunesConnect.
"TestFlight doesn’t support apps with Watchkit extension"
Does anyone have a idea why this is shown and what is the solution?

Comment: I duped a radar for this: http://openradar.appspot.com/20395363

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Apple TestFlight is not yet ready for WatchKit apps. You can temporarily disable WatchKit extension inclusion by deleting this row from main iOS app General Settings:

[image]

Comment: Why is my .appex listed in red in this setting? I did successfully build, archive, validate, and submit to iTunes Connect.

Comment: @AndrewDuncan try to delete and re-add it.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is via old school Ad Hoc or enterprise signing (and HockeyApp)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no solution, WatchKit apps cannot be distributed over TestFlight yet. I would estimate it will be enabled sometime after April 24 once the Apple Watch is released.

Comment: Just submitted an update of my app with watchkit extension (testflight 1.1) the internal testers (those with Apple watch) said testflight did not install the watch extension.  To piggyback on Christian Anchor Dampf's comment, It did install through Ad Hoc.

Comment: Scratch the above comment. Testflight clearly shows “Install on Apple Watch” (which by default was off)