# iTunes Connect prerelease build number warning symbol

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit

I uploaded a build to test flight with a WatchKit extension and am getting a warning symbol listed next to the build number for the build.

Does anyone know what this is about, how to fix it, if this means  there is an issue with the app when you submit for review, etc?

Thanks.

[image: build number pic]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTunes Connect yellow warning icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525873/itunes-connect-yellow-warning-icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there because Testflight doesn't support WatchKit extensions right now. You can still submit without any issues.

Comment: Is there some sort of documentation on this, I'll be happy to accept your answer if I can verify.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460048/testflight-doesn-t-support-apps-with-watchkit-extension

Comment: @Kris, here is the more detail information based on your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664036/what-does-the-warning-exclamation-mark-next-to-prerelease-builds-mean